# How do i work out the added 20% from the final result

Tags: divisibility, percentages

According to my employee contract because I am casual I am being paid with an extra 20% loading making my total being $22/h.

I wanted to work out how much I would normally have been paid if I wasn't a causal so I did

$(\frac{22}{100}) \times 20$

This would equal I am being paid an extra \$4.4 making my original pay $17.6/h. But then it hit me that this wouldn't be right because it would mean my current pay is 100% not 120% and I just worked out what 80% is.

The only other way I could try and work this out is going through every number between 1 and 22, getting what 1% is, multiplying that by 10 and adding it to my original number and checking if it was 22. To do that quickly I would have to write a program but there has to be a better way than going though every number.

So given how my pay of $22/h is 120% how can I work out what 100% is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the amount you would be getting paid be $x$

Then: $x+.20x=22$ so $x=(22)/(1+.20)=18.33$. You get paid  $3.67$  more.

Comment: thanks. it never occurred to me to divide by a number like 1.2. i tend to use those only for multiplication

Comment: 1.2 came from: you would make 22 dollars. This is the amount you would normally get paid (x) plus and extra 20% of that value. so x+.20x =x(1+.2)=x(1.2). Thats where the 1.2 comes from.